# Template specialization and const qualifier on type

Tags: c++, c++11

Why does the compiler expect separate specialization of a template on (concrete) types `T` and `const T`? Let me show an example. I had an unordered map keyed by a class type `Key`

```
std::unordered_map<Key, Value> data;
```

and for it to compile had to specialize `std::hash` on the type `Key` as

```
namespace std {
  template<>
  class hash<Key> { /* implementation */ };
}
```

However, when I changed the map type to

```
std::unordered_map<const Key, Value> data;
```

the compiler did not use my specialization and instead selected the generic `std::hash<T>`, which is little more than a compile time assert, until I specialized `std::hash<const Key>`.

Putting aside the utility of qualifying the map key type with `const`, why does not `const T` collapse to `T` when looking for a specialization in this case?

Also, could the template class `std::hash` (technically) be designed to allow such a collapse?

Comment: Simply because `T` and `const T` are different types by definition (unless `T` is already `const`). `std::hash` *could* have been designed to collapse that way, yes, but apparently it wasn't. Still a good question!

Comment: `std::unordered_map<const std::string, int>` doesn't compile either. So you don't need the custom key type to notice the problem. But normally, there is no need to use an explicit `const` type in a `std::{unordered_,}{multi,}map`, since the key is always `const`.

Comment: @rici: Good point about the `string` key! As for the const-ness of the key type, I indeed agree, but this is not my focus in the question.

Comment: @kkm: Understood. I promoted the comment to an answer; hope it helps somehow. If you want `std::unordered_map<const Key, Val>`, you could always be explicit about the hash parameter: `std::unordered_map<const Key, Val, std::hash<Key>>` would work fine. A more general solution is suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't really answer the "why", since it was a decision of the standards committee, who no doubt had their reasons.

The issue is not restricted to custom types. You can't instantiate `std::unordered_map<const std::string, int>` either.

Of course, it is rarely if ever useful to use an explicit `const` type as the key type of a standard associative container, since the value_type of the container is `std::pair<const Key, Val>`; the key is const regardless of its declared type. But I understand that is not related to the original question, and the `volatile` qualifier would have had the same effect.

Could it have been otherwise? Sure. It's not even that difficult:

```
template<typename Key,
         typename Val,
         typename Hash  = std::hash<typename std::remove_cv<Key>::type>,
         typename KeyEq = std::equal_to<Key>,
         typename Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, Val>>>
using my_unordered_map = std::unordered_map<Key, Val, Hash, KeyEq, Alloc>;
```

The only difference is the use of `std::remove_cv` in the default template argument for the `Hash` template parameter.

([Live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/088b3a7ccaaf9086).)